# xsp web server shuts down every time I change a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, mono

I've been brought on to help work on an existing ASP.NET app. I'm developing on a Mac using Visual Studio Community. I've got it all working but every time I change a single file (even an HTML file) the web server shuts down and I have to rebuild and run it again from Visual Studio.  Editing an HTML file should not shut down the server.

I've tried running xsp4 directly from the command line and I get a little more verbose output.

```
$ xsp4 --port 8080 
xsp4 
Listening on address: 0.0.0.0 
Root directory: /Users/admin/Documents/projects/xxx 
Listening on port: 8080 (non-secure) 
Hit Return to stop the server. 
Change: XXX.Sdk.dll 
Change: XXX.Sdk.dll 
Handling exception type AppDomainUnloadedException 
Message is Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain. 
IsTerminating is set to True 
Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain. 
Server stack trace:  
Exception rethrown at [0]:
 at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.DebugMain(string[],bool,Mono.WebServer.IApplicationHost,bool)
 at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.DebugMain(string[],bool,Mono.WebServer.IApplicationHost,bool)
 at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.DebugMain (System.String[] args, System.Boolean root, Mono.WebServer.IApplicationHost ext_apphost, System.Boolean quiet) [0x00252] in <645a23067666447e988a50155fe857f4>:0    
 at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.DebugMain (System.String[] args) [0x00032] in <645a23067666447e988a50155fe857f4>:0
 at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in <645a23067666447e988a50155fe857f4>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain.
```

You can see that it thinks `XXX.Sdk.dll` changed and that causes it to shut down.  I'm not sure WHY it thinks that file changed since all I did was edit an HTML file unrelated to that dll.

Is there a way to configure xsp4 to ignore ALL changes?

Comment: what version of mono is this?

Comment: @knocte `Mono JIT compiler version 5.12.0.301 (2018-02/4fe3280bba1 Fri Jul 20 08:25:42 EDT 2018)`

Comment: @knocte I also noticed you edited my title -- I understand that it's "not visual studio web server" but on OSX xsp4 is what visual studio community uses to run it's webserver (as opposed to IIS Express on windows).  Although my example shows me running `xsp4` from the CLI, the exact same behavior happens when I "Run" from visual studio

Comment: that means that it's very likely to be using xsp under the hood anyway, putting Visual Studio in the title is confusing (if anything, you should have written VS4mac)